# Extract data separated by multiple dots from a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

The cells contain different lengths of data. I tried text to column. It does not work because of the number of dots.

How can I populate each text or number in separate cells by ignoring the number of dots than delete the line anywhere there is an empty cell in column A and B?

Data exemple:
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: Is the dot the element to strip out when you apply Text to Columns?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried. Could you share the resulting cells' values for the first row of your data shown in the screenshot and where you want to put them?

Comment: @ALeXceL, Yes the dot is the element to strip ou

Comment: @VBasic2008 ,I only try text to column, I want to put them next to the data in different cell AC.1.TR.HTG.3100.900.HT.1M..NAB.6 AC 1 TR HTG 3100 900 HT 1M NAB 6
AC.1.TR.HTG.10070........2500.... AC 1 TR HTG 10070 2500

Comment: As mentioned by @VBasic2008, let others see what you've tried so far by commenting on possible failures. You'll get more answers (or faster answers, at least) and you won't risk having your question marked with a downvote.

Comment: If the value is in cell `A1`, will `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"."," "))` do the job? If not, please do clarify.

Comment: What about a dot in-between numbers? Would you know for sure you want to split `111.222` for example?

Comment: @VBasic2008, good, It's working, the formula remove all dots and add a blank space which will easily work with text to column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Split Data

**Associated**

```vb
Sub SplitAssociated()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "B1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1)
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        rCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = sws.Evaluate("TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" & srg.Address & ",""."","" ""))")
     
    Dim SubStrings() As Variant: ReDim SubStrings(1 To rCount)
    Dim Lens() As Long: ReDim Lens(1 To rCount)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    Dim cString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        cString = Data(r, 1)
        If Len(cString) > 0 Then
            SubStrings(r) = Split(cString)
            Lens(r) = UBound(SubStrings(r)) + 1
            If Lens(r) > cCount Then cCount = Lens(r)
        End If
    Next r
    
    ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To Lens(r)
            Data(r, c) = SubStrings(r)(c - 1)
        Next c
    Next r
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = Data
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount).Clear

End Sub
```

**Remove Blanks**

```vb
Sub SplitRemoveBlanks()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "C1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1)
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        srCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = sws.Evaluate("TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" & srg.Address & ",""."","" ""))")
     
    Dim SubStrings() As Variant: ReDim SubStrings(1 To srCount)
    Dim Lens() As Long: ReDim Lens(1 To srCount)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim drCount As Long
    Dim dcCount As Long
    Dim cString As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        cString = Data(sr, 1)
        If Len(cString) > 0 Then
            drCount = drCount + 1
            SubStrings(sr) = Split(cString)
            Lens(sr) = UBound(SubStrings(sr)) + 1
            If Lens(sr) > dcCount Then dcCount = Lens(sr)
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If Lens(sr) > 0 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For dc = 1 To Lens(sr)
                Data(dr, dc) = SubStrings(sr)(dc - 1)
            Next dc
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    drg.Value = Data
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: The `If Len(cString) > 0 Then` in the first (`Associated`) solution was in the wrong place and was redundant since `For c = 1 To 0` will not enter the inner loop anyway, so I removed it. Sorry.

Comment: Can the clear function delete the entire row even if other cells in the row have data?  Because the split column have important data in the same cell. After the code run the split column shift up and left other data below.    Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the "." (dot) is the element to be stripped from strings in cells (eg no floating point numbers, nor "." is an important mark), you can use this code including deleting entire lines.

The code loops through the specified range (oRng) and when it finds ".." it will replace it with ".". Then, when no more ".." is found, indicating that the replacement job has completed, generating an error (caught), it proceeds to delete the blank rows from the blank cells in column "A".

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnCleanAndSplit()
    Dim oRng As Excel.Range
    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim fDone As Boolean

    Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A7")

    Do
        For Each oCell In oRng.Cells
            oCell.Value = VBA.Replace(oCell.Value, "..", ".")
        Next
        On Error GoTo lblDone
        fDone = oRng.Find("..") = ""
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop Until fDone
    
lblDone:
    oRng.TextToColumns Destination:=oRng.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=".", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    oRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    oRng.Parent.Activate 'just in case it is not activated
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Comment: wonderful, it works when I use it on small range, I tried on about 300k lines of data in column "B", where "A" have other useful data the macro stops at this line "Selection.EntireRow.Delete"

Comment: What I realize in column "B" where there is blank cell there is also useless data in column "A", maybe that's the reason the delete function does not work

Comment: @JamesLaguerre Yes, this macro should be used on column 1 ("A"). Switching to work with column "B" will only evaluate cells in column "B" without evaluating what is in column "A". You can also work with Power Query to get more control over these text splitting.